# Copying data from multiple workbooks to single work book sheet wise

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data available in multiple worksheets in multiple workbooks into another workbook but sheet wise and data should have one column of workbook name(from where it has been copied).
For example
Workbook1 name(Raju-can be any name) having 7 sheets with different name(sheet name are same in both workbook)
Workbook2 name(pappu-can be any name) having 7 sheets with different name

Copy in new workbook sheet wise ..in result workbook(first sheet should have all the data from first sheet of wkb 1 and wkb 2 and same thing for second sheet)...and in all the sheet workbook name should be there that from which workbook data is copied.

Thanks in advance for help..

```
Option Explicit

Const ROW_FIRST As Integer = 2

Const BREAK_SHEET = 100000

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub getFiles_Click()

'Creating Variables

Dim intResult As Integer, i As Double, strPath As String, objFSO As Object, intCountRows As Integer

Dim fileMap As New Scripting.dictionary

Dim fileName As Variant, filePath As String, sheet As Worksheet, openWb As Workbook

Dim sourceRange As String, noOfRecordsCopied As Double, noOfFilesScanned As Double, wbSheet As Worksheet

Set fileMap = New dictionary

'Initializing variables

i = ROW_FIRST

noOfRecordsCopied = 0

noOfFilesScanned = 0

'Get location of files to be copied

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = "Select a Path"

intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

'Get all excel files in the selected location

If intResult <> 0 Then

    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    intCountRows = GetAllFiles(strPath, ROW_FIRST, objFSO, fileMap)

    Call GetAllFolders(strPath, objFSO, intCountRows, fileMap)

End If

'Add all the records to this excel

Dim sheetNo As Double

sheetNo = 1

For Each fileName In fileMap.Keys

    'Get the Funds required for Equity from T-2 File

    If (fileName Like "*.xl*") Then

        Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(fileMap(fileName))

        For Each sheet In openWb.Worksheets



            If i = ROW_FIRST Or i + sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count > BREAK_SHEET Then

                Set wbSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))

                wbSheet.Name = "Sheet" & sheetNo

                sheetNo = sheetNo + 1

                sheet.Range("1:1").Copy Destination:=wbSheet.Range("1:1")

                wbSheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert

                wbSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Name of File"

                i = ROW_FIRST

            End If

            sourceRange = "A2:" & ConvertToLetter(sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count) & sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            sheet.Range(sourceRange).Copy Destination:=wbSheet.Range("B" & i)

            wbSheet.Range("A" & i & ":A" & (i + sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2)).Value = fileName

            i = i + sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

            noOfRecordsCopied = noOfRecordsCopied + sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

            noOfFilesScanned = noOfFilesScanned + 1

        Next sheet

        openWb.Close (False)

    End If

Next fileName

'Enter statistics

Cells(4, 2) = noOfRecordsCopied

Cells(5, 2) = noOfFilesScanned

Sheets("Collator").Activate

End Sub



Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal intRow As Integer, ByRef objFSO As Object, ByRef fileMap As Scripting.dictionary) As Integer

Dim objFolder As Object, objFile As Object, i As Integer

i = intRow - ROW_FIRST + 1

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    fileMap(objFile.Name) = objFile.Path

    i = i + 1

Next objFile

GetAllFiles = i + ROW_FIRST - 1

End Function



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Private Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, ByRef objFSO As Object, ByRef intRow As Integer, ByRef fileMap As Scripting.dictionary)

Dim objFolder As Object, objSubFolder As Object

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subFolders

    intRow = GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, intRow, objFSO, fileMap)

    Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, objFSO, intRow, fileMap)

Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid you are in the wrong site. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I have code to collate worksheet from different workbooks into one workbook it tells from which workbook it has compiled data but I need sheet name coloumn also ..that from which sheet the data has been copied...I need just little help..

Comment: Please show us your code, explicity stating were the problem lies.

Comment: I have added code....I want to add sheet name from which it has been copied.....this code copy data from workbooks from different sheet into collator sheet and it has column from which it has been copied...I just need sheet name also beside data

Comment: This code is giving correct data but I just need sheet name to be displayed in one column....

Comment: CMArg plz help..

Comment: Really I can't properly understand your code. I'm not an expert, but I think your code is much more complex than needed. Anyway, for the sheet name, replece `wbSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Name of File"` with `wbSheet.Range("A1").Value = sheet.name`

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, check out the AddIn from the URL below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]